# Can we develop VNext projects using Apache Tomcat or Wildfly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I don't know whether this question should be posted over here but I am too keen to know the answer. 
Can we develop VNext/.net projects using Apache Tomcat or Wildfly. I heard .net projects can be hosted on Tomcat but can we use a non IIS servers for development using visual studio?
No offence, with a great respect to IIS and Microsoft.
Thank you!

Comment: Check rhe following link for more information: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servers

Comment: Thank you! It cleared most of my doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably got some wrong information from unknown sources.

ASP.NET 5 is going to support cross platform, but it still needs a hosting environment, currently [Kestrel](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servers) as @CodeNotFound pointed out.

Once ASP.NET 5 runs there, Apache or Nginx can be used as reverse proxy to route requests to Kestrel/ASP.NET side. That's the current "no-IIS" approach for OS X or Linux.

Thus, I don't think Tomcat or Wildfly is relevant here.

Meanwhile, for development, you can use [Visual Studio Code](http://code.visualstudio.com) or any editor you like (with [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/)). Visual Studio on Windows is still the best IDE but it is optional this time.